# Java parsing truetype font to extract each characters as image & its code

Tags: java, fonts, truetype

Is there any java library that can be used to extract each character from a true type font (.ttf)?

Each character of the font, I want to:

1. Convert it to the image
2. Extract its code (ex: Unicode value)

Anyone can help to show me some tips on above purpose?

P.S: I want to figure out, how such this app made: http://www.softpedia.com/progScreenshots/CharMap-Screenshot-94863.html

Comment: I don't think it is converting the character to image, the application is just writing each character in different labels with the selected font

Comment: Yes and my purpose will convert the character the image but I wonder how to get each character from the font as they made? And can we extract each character to bitmap file?

Comment: As i said, it is very unlikely that they converted the char to image, it is a memory waste, they certainly just printed each character to the proper label, converting it to an image would decrease the application performance and waste memory

Comment: @BackSlash Yes, I know but I said my purpose I want to get each design of the character, I don't do like them, I have a purpose behind this. So I want to know if possible we can extract each character from the font (the design attribute) and its code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will convert a `String` to a `BufferedImage`:

```java
public BufferedImage stringToBufferedImage(String s) {
    //First, we have to calculate the string's width and height

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();

    //Set the font to be used when drawing the string
    Font f = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 48);
    g.setFont(f);

    //Get the string visual bounds
    FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontMetrics().getFontRenderContext();
    Rectangle2D rect = f.getStringBounds(s, frc);
    //Release resources
    g.dispose();

    //Then, we have to draw the string on the final image

    //Create a new image where to print the character
    img = new BufferedImage((int) Math.ceil(rect.getWidth()), (int) Math.ceil(rect.getHeight()), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    g = img.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black); //Otherwise the text would be white
    g.setFont(f);

    //Calculate x and y for that string
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    int x = 0;
    int y = fm.getAscent(); //getAscent() = baseline
    g.drawString(s, x, y);

    //Release resources
    g.dispose();

    //Return the image
    return img;
}
```

I think there isn't a way to get all the characters, you have to create a `String` or a `char` array where you store all the chars you want to convert to image.

Once you have the `String` or `char[]` with all keys you want to convert, you can easily iterate over it and convert call the `stringToBufferedImage` method, then you can do

```java
int charCode = (int) charactersMap.charAt(counter);
```

if `charactersMap` is a `String`, or

```java
int charCode = (int) charactersMap[counter];
```

if `charactersMap` is a `char` array

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it's working for Khmer unicode as well.

BufferedImage img = stringToBufferedImage("ក");
System.out.println(img);
File outputfile = new File("c:/tmp/saved.png");
ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);

Comment: I am testing fontbox library to see if it can extract all characters from font or not. Currently I could extract postscript name/unicode value of each character

Comment: This solution more likely help me some part, of course to work directly from truetype font still another challenge but I still read using fontbox to get each unicode string and convert to to corresponding character, I will do that. Thanks for solution above.

Comment: I have a question on how to keep output image data of 32x32 pixels? Since some characters with given font size, they generate different size of picture generated?